# How to turn a function's input argument into a new function

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I want to write a function via a module that takes a user's input and creates a function from the input within the module.

That is something like

Input:

```
G[nterm_] := 
  Module[{n, r},
    r[n_] := nterm
    r[n+1]]

G[n^2]
```

Output:

> `(n+1)^2`

Comment: My math must be slipping: how did you get from $n^2$ to $(n+1)^2$?

Comment: It should return a function or just an expression like above?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, please let me put in in context.. I'm implementing Gosper's algorithm (page 87 of A=B: https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/), so it needs to take a hypergeometric term as input and convert it to a rational function (or expression?) r(n) = t(n+1)/t(n) then execute a series of loops etc. The problems arise in the loops where the function definition is updated throughout. Simply defining a function f[n_]:=blah and trying to update it's definition in a loop doesn't seem to work. It seems replacement rules using /.-> might offer the solution.. not sure though?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason to use `Module` for what you seem to asking. I suggest

```
g[expr_, var_Symbol] := If[FreeQ[expr, var], $Failed, expr /. var -> var + 1]
```

Then

```
g[n^2, n]
```

> `(1 + n)^2`

```
g[2 Sqrt[x] + y^x, x]
```

> `2 Sqrt[1 + x] + y^(1 + x)`

but

```
g[a + Sqr[x], y]
```

> `$Failed`